# How do I open a specific commit in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio

In TFSVC, I was able to open a changeset and view the differences in files by using the following command, for example: **TF changeset 111111**.

I would like to achieve the same functionality with Git. It doesn't necessarily have to be within the Visual Studio IDE; I would be satisfied if I could do this in tools like VS Code or Fork as well. Currently, I'm using **git diff** for this purpose, but I find it slower to manually navigate through files in the command line compared to using an IDE.

Below is the functionality in visual studio

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Find your commit in the git history graph
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-browse-repository?view=vs-2022#browse-through-local-and-remote-branches

And after that it's as easy as double clicking to see commit details.

Comment: I want to be able to do this from the command line. This is through the IDE so it is really not what I am asking for.

Comment: @StuartSmith from cli you want to launch a GUI tool? I don't think it's possible with VS. Maybe you can try 'tig' or 'gitk' both provided with git. Otherwise try to find an extension for Vscode doing that. Otherwise, investigate fork command line options.

Answer (score -2):

To see the differences for individual files, **first and most importantly, make sure that you are on a clean working directory already** (meaning that you have either committed or stashed your most recent changes).

You can run the command, `git reset <blob>` (replace `<blob>` with the actual commit ID from a previous blob). Then, run `git status` to see all of your changes since that blob.

With your list of file names, you can copy any file name and then paste it into the following command where `<fileName>` is: `git diff <fileName>`.

When you're done looking at changes, you can do a hard reset, using `git reset --hard <blob>`, to return to the blob which you came from.

Comment: He wants to see the content of a commit, not reset current branch on this commit. Even checkout the commit is a better idea than that.....

Comment: @Philippe Resetting to the previous blob is completely temporary. Have I not made this clear enough? It sounds like he wants to see the overall difference between the current blob and a previous commit from the command line, and this would enable him to do that. Can you explain what you mean by "checkout the commit is a better idea"? Because I never implied you have to do this on your current branch or any specific branch in particular. You can switch to a new branch, sure. I never said you couldn't.